# Get Last Date of Given Month and Year in c#

Tags: c#

i want c# code for getting Last Date of week for given month and year.

suppose given month is 1 and year is 2016 then method should return me

```
--01/02/2016
--01/09/2016
--01/16/2016
--01/23/2016
--01/30/2016
--02/06/2016
```

Comment: So you are really saying that you want all the Saturdays in the given month, and if the last Saturday is not the last day of the month also the first Saturday of the next Month?

Comment: Did you try anything ?

Comment: Why `02/06/2016`? How is februar related to "last date of january 2016"? I would understand your expected result if the first day of your week is sunday and if you had only january dates. Note that your title is misleading. You don't want to get the last date of a given month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a method which takes a year and a month as parameter and returns dates. Those dates should be the last dates of all weeks in that month, optionally also of following months.

This should work then:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetLastWeekDatesOfMonth(int year, int month, DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday, bool includeLaterMonths = false)
{ 
    DateTime first = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    int daysOffset = (int)firstDayOfWeek - (int)first.DayOfWeek;
    if (daysOffset < 0)
        daysOffset = 7 - Math.Abs(daysOffset);
    DateTime firstWeekDay = first.AddDays(daysOffset);
    DateTime current = firstWeekDay.AddDays(-1); // last before week start
    if (current.Month != month)
        current = current.AddDays(7);
    yield return current;
    if (includeLaterMonths)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            current = current.AddDays(7);
            yield return current;
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        while((current = current.AddDays(7)).Month == month)
            yield return current;
    }
}
```

Your sample:

```
var lastDates = GetLastWeekDatesOfMonth(2016, 1, DayOfWeek.Sunday, true);
foreach (DateTime dt in lastDates.Take(6))
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

public static DateTime GetLastDateofWeek(int yr, int mnth, int week)
        {
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(yr, mnth, 1);
            DateTime newdate = new DateTime();
            if (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
            {
                newdate = dt.AddDays(((week - 1) * 7) + 5);
            }
            else
            {
                newdate = dt.AddDays((8 - (int)dt.DayOfWeek) % 7 + ((week - 2) * 7) + 5);
            }
            return newdate;
        }

Answer (score 0):

First get month and year, example:

```
int year = 2016;
int month = 1;
```

And then create a new instance of the DateTime class that represents the first saturday.

```
DateTime firstsaturday = new DateTime(year,month,1);

while(firstsaturday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    firstsaturday = firstsaturday.AddDays(1);
]
```

Then create a List of DateTime values.

```
List<DateTime> saturdays = new List<DateTime>();

saturdays.Add(firstsaturday);
```

And then cycle through all saturdays using a loop.

```
DateTime CurrentSaturday = firstsaturday;

while(CurrentSaturday.AddDays(7).Month == month)
{
    CurrentSaturday = CurrentSaturday.AddDays(7);
    Saturdays.Add(CurrentSaturday);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this code.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime thisMonthInLastYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
        DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(thisMonthInLastYear.Year, 
                                   thisMonthInLastYear.Month, 
                                   DateTime.DaysInMonth(thisMonthInLastYear.Year, 
                                                        thisMonthInLastYear.Month));
        
        Console.WriteLine("Today : "+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

        Console.WriteLine("This Month in last years : "+endOfMonth.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
        Console.WriteLine("Next month in last years : "+endOfMonth.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some support code and an explanation of your own to your answer. Just a link that may be outdated sooner or later is not a good answer. Thanks for understanding!